# dd: /dev/rdisk3: Invalid argument

Tags: sd-card

I'm attempting to burn the latest raspbian image to a microSD card on a mac (macos sierra: 10.12.6) following the official instructions for doing so.

[INSTALLING OPERATING SYSTEM IMAGES ON MAC OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md)

I've done this many times before without difficulty but recently something has changed which is is generating this error:

```
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Invalid argument
```

Interestingly, this error occurs both

1. when I use the version of dd that comes with macos and
2. when I use the version of dd from gnu coreutils (installed via homebrew)

   >which --all dd
    /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/dd
    /bin/dd

**with macos dd:**

```
    >date; sudo /bin/dd bs=1m if=2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/rdisk3; date
Sun Aug  6 12:24:33 PDT 2017
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Invalid argument
4445+1 records in
4445+0 records out
4660920320 bytes transferred in 189.129174 secs (24644111 bytes/sec)
Sun Aug  6 12:27:42 PDT 2017
```

**with gnu dd:**

```
    >date; sudo dd bs=1M if=2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/rdisk3; date
Sun Aug  6 11:50:48 PDT 2017
Password:
dd: error writing '/dev/rdisk3': Invalid argument
4445+1 records in
4445+0 records out
4660920320 bytes (4.7 GB, 4.3 GiB) copied, 189.93 s, 24.5 MB/s
Sun Aug  6 11:54:04 PDT 2017
```

Switching from "/dev/rdisk3" to "/dev/disk3" seems to make the error go away but it take 20 minutes to complete instead of 3 minutes.

**/dev/rdisk3 => /dev/disk3**

```
    >date; sudo /bin/dd bs=1m if=2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/disk3; date
Sun Aug  6 12:35:20 PDT 2017
4445+1 records in
4445+1 records out
4661483821 bytes transferred in 1213.807451 secs (3840382 bytes/sec)
Sun Aug  6 12:55:34 PDT 2017
```

3 minutes is preferable to 20.
In the past rdisk has worked without error.
Given that this error occurs with both versions of dd and the source code for each is quite different, I'm guessing that the error is occurring during the mounting stage at the end of the burning. i.e. dd is making a sys call to mount the volume and this sys call is returning the error (I think).

2 questions:

1. Does anyone know for certain why this error is being generated?
2. The volume seems to actually mount, so is it safe to ignore the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in the latest image. It is **NOT** a complete number of blocks (as indicated by the +1).

It should be possible to burn it by using `dd` parameters to write incomplete blocks `dd conv=sync` (I have not tried this), but the current workaround is to use `Etcher`.

Future images will consist of complete blocks.

Comment: this is the correct answer, thank you ! Other google results suggest changing `rdisk#` to `disk#`, but that halves throughput for some reason.

Comment: @Eric `rdisk` is "raw" disk mode aka a character mode device, rather than a block mode device, which is buffered by the OS. If you look in `/dev` you will see both. `disk#` is slower, sometimes only 10% but at other times can take 10 times as long. Generally you can only use raw mode on an unmounted drive. See `man hdiutil`